# How to declare boost range adaptor (e.g. map_values)

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, dictionary, boost-range

Say I have

```
class Value;
class Key;

class MyClass {
  private:
  std::map<Key,Value> my_map;
  ....
}
```

Inside of MyClass methods I have a very convenient way to iterate through values of my_map by saying

```
 for( auto& value: my_map | boost::adaptors::map_values) {
    ...
 }
```

However I would like to have a method of MyClass that would essentially output
     my_map | boost::adaptors::map_values
and allow convenient value iteration outside of MyClass methods. How do I declare such a method? Would I need to implement some sort of pseudo container and corresponding iterator or there is a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have two good choices.  You can provide users with a nicely decoupled interface by using boost's `any_range`, or else if you need the best performance, you can give clients direct access to the adapted range using c++11 decltypes.  In the first case, clients won't have to change if you change implementation, but this comes at a cost of extra redirection.

using `any_range`:

```
#include <boost/range.hpp> 
#include <map> 
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp> 
#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>

class Foo 
{ 
    std::map<int, int> my_map;
    boost::any_range<int, boost::forward_traversal_tag, int&, std::ptrdiff_t> Values()
    { return my_map | boost::adaptors::map_values; }
};
```

giving direct access (awkward syntax here is because you require VS2013, which doesn't support member variables in unevaluated context at class scope):

```
#include <boost/range.hpp> 
#include <map> 
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp> 

class Foo 
{ 
    std::map<int, int> my_map;
    auto Values() -> decltype(my_map | boost::adaptors::map_values)
    { return my_map | boost::adaptors::map_values; }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't compile in VS2013

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were using VS2013.  In general, if you want answers to work in VS2013, you should mention that in your question as Microsoft still doesn't support the C++11 standard.  My code would have worked on any C++11 compiler, but I just edited it to work in visual studio as well.

Comment: @rmcclelan Thanks for your help. I still can't make it to work. I placed your typedef as well as Values() method inside of class declaration right after declaration of my_map and it does not compile in VS2013.

Comment: LRaiz, could you provide an error message?  Thanks.

Comment: First here is my code  (soory still can't master markdown) 
    #include <boost/range.hpp>  
    #include <map>  
    #include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>  

    class Foo {  
     std::map<int, int> my_map;  
     typedef boost::iterator_range<decltype((my_map |     boost::adaptors::map_values).begin())> values_range;  
     values_range Values() {  
      return values_range(my_map |     boost::adaptors::map_values);  
     }  
    };

Comment: First couple of errors
Error 1 error C2678: binary '|' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'unknown' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    

Error 2 error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union

Comment: okay, edited again with a re-write that should be okay in VS2013.

Comment: Super. Thanks for finding a workaround for VS2013 C++11 deficiencies.

Comment: @rmcclelan - VS2013 gives me headaches. 'ugly' options compiles and is usable in range for statement. However it does not allow Values().size() forcing workarounds.

Comment: boost::any_range<Value, boost::forward_traversal_tag, Value&, std::ptrdiff_t> Values()  { return my_map | boost::adaptors::map_values; } leads to compiler error Error 1 error C2039: 'distance_to' : is not a member of 'boost::range_detail::any_forward_iterator_interface<Reference,Buffer>'

Comment: @rmcclelan provided a solution that works well but now I am having troubles trying to extend it. What would be a correct syntax to get range iterators for const values as opposed to mutable ones? Especially which solution would work with the latest VS2013 which still does not like boost::anyRange?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't strictly necessary to use a pseudo container or an iterator adapter, such as boost::iterator_range. Although using a proper adapter such as iterator_range would theoretically be more correct and versatile, and will not violate the [principle of least knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) as applied to objects, you may want to avoid it because of an additional indirection, or maybe because your iterator is  generally only a single-pass range and not a forward range.

So if you wish to use the adapted range directly you can simply use `decltype` to deduce the iterator type already returned by the adaptor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>

class A {
  std::map<int,int> my_map = { {0, 1}, {2, 3} };
public:
  decltype(my_map | boost::adaptors::map_values)
  values() { return my_map | boost::adaptors::map_values; }
};

int main() {
    for (const auto& v : A().values())
        std::cout << "v = " << v << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
/* Output:
v = 1
v = 3
*/
```

And if you want the exposed values to be a const member function it's slightly more intricate:

```
class A { 
...
  decltype(const_cast<const std::map<int,int>&>(my_map) | boost::adaptors::map_values)
  values() const { return my_map | boost::adaptors::map_values; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code below doesn't compile with VS2013.    
     #include <map>
     #include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>

     class Bar {
        std::map<int, int> _myMap;
        decltype(_myMap | boost::adaptors::map_values)  values() { return _myMap | boost::adaptors::map_values; }
      }

Comment: Error 1 error C2678: binary '|' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'unknown' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   


Error 2 error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'boost::range_detail::select_second_mutable_range<std::map<int,int,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>' to 'int'

Comment: @LRaiz 1. Of course this code is valid C++11, it compiles and works, [see it live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eed284f289b110ab), 2. the tags you have specified for the question did not include VS, so I don't see why you have unaccepted it. It may be best to investigate the limitations of visual-studio in a separate question. (And you need the Nov CTP release to get the best subset of C++11 feature for VS.)